# "wasn't it you,the one that made the cake" or "weren't it you,the one that made the cake"

Tags: grammar

"wasn't it you,the one that made the cake" or "weren't it you,the one that made the cake"

which one is correct and why?

Comment: "Did you make  the cake?"

Comment: Close the first question and see if that makes grammatical sense first. Is the question grammatical and complete? *Wasn't it you?* or *Weren't it you?* That might give you your answer for this form.

Comment: 'Was it not yourself who made the cake ?' This bears an even stronger emphasis (assuming that is what is required) than the above, the emphasis being that, yes, it _was_ you who did the deed.

Comment: To make the long answers short: The subject of "was" or "were" is "it" (not "you"), so "was" is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are turning into a question "It was you who ...". The alternative question "It were you who..." is not standard  English, but is certainly heard in some dialects.

So, unless you are clearly writing in one such dialect, and if you want to form your question in that manner, rather than in the manner that @Hot Licks suggests, then your first suggestion is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If we expand the contractions, then the answer should be more obvious:

"wasn't it you..." becomes "was it not you".

"weren't it you" becomes "were it not you".

And if we rearrange the structure to be more straightforward, we are left with "was it you" versus "were it you". The first option should seem correct.

Now if the structure was different, that might change, for example: "Were you the one" is correct instead of "Was you the one".

It's may seem a bit tricky at first when you break it down like this, but when in doubt this method can help spot the differences.